# Docker tomcat run as root inside non-root container: security issues?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, security, docker-compose, tomcat9

docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/myapp/data /path/myapp/data
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

The tomcat image is run as root, not non-root user like "tomcat". It has volume and port bind to host.

If starting docker-compose as non-root user (e.g., myapp_user),

```
 docker-compose up
```

Any security issue for running Tomcat as root inside a container(running as non-root) on Ubuntu?